# Why this single quotes and braces in output in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, python-2.x

I am using ipython notebook in ubantu version 16.04 and I run this code,

```
word = 'Rushiraj'
length = 0
for char in 'rushiraj':
    length = length + 1
print('There are', length,'character')
```

I get this output:
('There are', 8, 'character')

What is the reason for this single quotes and round braces in output ?It should not be there !

Comment: You are using Python 2 to run code meant for Python 3.

Comment: ^This. Try `print 'There are', length,'character' `

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The output you are seeing is due to the fact that you are using Python 2, but you're using the `print` syntax from Python 3.  In Python 3, `print` is a function and takes arguments like other functions (as in `print(...)`).

In Python 2, `print` is a statement, and by using parentheses you are actually passing it a `tuple` as its first argument (so you are printing out the  Python representation of a tuple).

You can fix this in two ways.

If you add `from __future__ import print_function` to the top of your file, then `print` will behave like it does in Python 3.

Alternately, you can call it like:

```
print 'There are', length,'character'
```

Comment: how can I switch to python 3 from python 2 ? @larsks

Comment: He is obviously using Python 2, but indicates he wants to switch to Python 3.

Comment: Perhaps I was tired and misread the comment.  I thought it said the opposite last night, but there it is!  @R.Brahmbhatt, that question is actually too big to answer in a comment.  Depending on your system, you may be able to type `python3` and have it installed already, or you may need to figure out how to install a Python 3 interpreter, which varies between operating systems and linux distributions.

Comment: thank for reaching back but I find the solution @larsks I just set the python 3 as default but setting the alias !

Answer (score 0):

You're printing a tuple (even though it may not appear that way at first glance), so the output is the repr of that tuple.

Comment: I didn't say print called `__repr__`; I said the output is the repr of the tuple. `tuple.__str__` just calls `tuple.__repr__`.